# Добавление названия класса при клике через onclick()

Tags: javascript

Код:
http://jsfiddle.net/qn7JG/1/

Требуется при клике на ссылку передать this в качестве парамера в функции onclick().
И уже в обработчике добавить к этой ссылке название нового класса.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно так: http://jsfiddle.net/qn7JG/22/

HTML:

```
<div id="res">
    <a href="" class="ff" data-lat="123" data-lon="321" data-balloontext="text123">textr123</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("selected");
    console.log($this.data("lat"));
    console.log($this.data("lon"));
    console.log($this.data("balloontext"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Если уж вы используете `jQuery`, то и делайте в стиле `jQuery`:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault(); // отменяем действия перехода
});
```

Если хотите передать еще вдобавок какие-то параметры, то используйте атрибут `data`:

`html`:

```
<a href='#' data-number="10" data-class="selected"></a>
```

`js`:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass($(this).data('class'));
    e.preventDefault(); // отменяем действия перехода
});
```

В вашем же случае нужно поступить так:

```
<a href="" class="ff" onclick="return go_to(123, 321,'text123', this, event)">textr123</a>
```

То есть добавить параметр `event` в вызов функции. Плюс на `jsfiddle` у вас не рабочий код, т.к. функция go_to располагается не в глобальной области видимости) Выносите её из `window.onload`.